# Redirecting whole domain but retaining admin access on specific IP

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to create a redirect in .htaccess that will send all customers / visitors to a single down for maintenance page.

However, I would like to retain access for myself (on a specific IP address) to an admin area or ideally the whole domain

So far I have this for the whole domain redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/maintenance[R=301,L]
```

I had also looked at something like this to allow my IP to access:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 12.34.567.890
```

However I don't think this would work together and I am a bit out of my depth.

I would be really grateful for some guidance please.

Paul

Comment: Add a RewriteCond that checks `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` …

Comment: What version of Apache are you using? Don't use a 301 redirect, since any user that visits during the maintenance period will "forever" be stuck in maintenance mode. Consider serving a [503 Service Unavailable](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55659/1243) instead.

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure how to do this?

Comment: I went into detail about how to implement this in the linked question above on the Webmasters Stack. Which bit are you stuck on?